# crash problem with iOS using PlivoVoiceKit

Tags: ios, crash, plivo

using 'PlivoVoiceKit'. When we call the login method ([self.endpoint login: AndPassword: DeviceToken: CertificateId:];) All parameters have values and are correct, but some users will crash.

```
pj_throw_exception_
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000101f3e3b4
0
PlivoVoiceKit
pj_throw_exception_ + 116
1
PlivoVoiceKit
int_parse_name_addr + 372
2
PlivoVoiceKit
int_parse_uri_or_name_addr + 88
3
PlivoVoiceKit
parse_hdr_contact + 168
4
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_parse_hdr + 148
5
PlivoVoiceKit
set_contact + 204
6
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_regc_update_contact + 88
7
PlivoVoiceKit
regc_tsx_callback + 708
8
PlivoVoiceKit
mod_util_on_tsx_state + 204
9
PlivoVoiceKit
tsx_set_state + 564
10
PlivoVoiceKit
tsx_on_state_proceeding_uac + 944
11
PlivoVoiceKit
tsx_on_state_calling + 560
12
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_tsx_recv_msg + 232
13
PlivoVoiceKit
mod_tsx_layer_on_rx_response + 236
14
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data + 632
15
PlivoVoiceKit
endpt_on_rx_msg + 576
16
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_tpmgr_receive_packet + 1816
17
PlivoVoiceKit
on_data_read + 180
18
PlivoVoiceKit
asock_on_data_read + 516
19
PlivoVoiceKit
ioqueue_on_read_complete + 184
20
PlivoVoiceKit
ioqueue_dispatch_read_event + 828
21
PlivoVoiceKit
pj_ioqueue_poll + 1200
22
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 + 260
23
PlivoVoiceKit
pjsua_handle_events + 68
24
PlivoVoiceKit
worker_thread + 52
25
PlivoVoiceKit
thread_main + 160
26
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_start + 320
27
libsystem_pthread.dylib
thread_start + 8
```

We did not encounter this problem in our development, but after the same parameter value is put online, users will appear and crash in the sdk of PlivoVoiceKit, resulting in us not being able to see the specific problem information